# Use integral2 or integral3 to calculate CDF in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, numerical-integration

I just encountered a problem using `integral2` or `integral3` to calculate CDFs in MATLAB. Suppose I have two independent normal random variables X and Y, the mean value vector is `mu = [5;50]`, and the covariance matrix is `c = [3^2,0; 0,3^2]`.

Since they are independent, the joint PDF is the multiplication of the two PDFs, I used the following code to compute the probability over the whole domain,

```
integral2(@(x,y) normpdf(x,5,3).*normpdf(y,50,3),-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf)
```

I think it should give me `1` as the answer, but instead, it returns

```
1.8174e-10
```

Then I tried the `mvncdf` function,

```
mvncdf([Inf,Inf],[5,50],diag([3,3].^2))
```

and it returns the right answer, `1`. I also tried the 1D version `integral`, which works fine. Can anyone please explain this for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring due to [numerical imprecision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) (combined with the fact that your distributions have non-zero means). You can use the [`'AbsTol'` option for `integral2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html#input_argument_namevalue_d119e517269) to increase the solution accuracy:

```
integral2(@(x,y)normpdf(x,5,3).*normpdf(y,50,3),-Inf,Inf,-Inf,Inf,'AbsTol',1e-16)
```

returns something closer to `1`. You can avoid this by taking advantage of symmetry about the means of your distributions, e.g.,

```
4*integral2(@(x,y)normpdf(x,5,3).*normpdf(y,50,3),5,Inf,50,Inf)
```

Your `mvncdf` example uses a completely different method to directly calculate something like this:

```
normcdf(Inf,5,3)*normcdf(Inf,50,3)
```